# Are any guns in Planetside 2 'hitscan'?

Tags: planetside-2

Hitscan weapons mean that the bullet has no travel time/velocity, and they hit where the crosshair is at the instant of clicking(not taking lag into account). I notice some guns have a bullet velocity here, so I wonder if any of the guns are hitscan that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every single weapon is not hitscan. One thing to remember though is that all weapons have very different bullet velocities. some being high enough to think its hitscan (most Vanu Sovereignty weapons have the highest bullet speed while New Conglomerate is slow as molasses shells).